# Reputation number in the top bar hard to read

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Apparently a new feature has been added recently, so that you can now click on your reputation number and get to the privileges page, meaning the reputation number is now a link.

However this feature seems to interact badly with gaming's design, making the number hard to read as it is now almost as dark as the background:

[image: Hard to read rep number]

The color should be changed back to white, so that it's readable again.

Browser: Firefox 3.6

Comment: Yeah, I don't know when this changed, but I stopped by Meta now solely to report this.

Comment: Unrelatedly, the link gives me a 404...

Comment: @badp: That one has already been reported on MSO: [Reputation link leads to a Page Not Found on per-site metas](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67835/reputation-link-leads-to-a-page-not-found-on-per-site-metas)

Comment: Forgot to mention: Reproduced in Firefox 3.6.10 Windows, IE 8.0.7600.16385 Windows 7, Chrome 6.0.472.63 Windows, and Opera 10.63 Windows.

Comment: Wanted to report this too. Also affecting SeaMonkey 2.0.8 in Windows.

Comment: Can reproduce on Safari 5.0.1 and 5.0.2 on Mac OS X 10.6 as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this is now completed.